# Seeding Laravel Package To Sqlite for Codeception with Composer Command

Tags: laravel, sqlite, composer-php

I want to automate my package seeding somewhat by creating a command within my composer.json file however whenever I run the command I get Class 'Namespace\Module\Classname' does not exist.

here is what my composer.json command looks like:

```
"seedsqlite-cmd": [
        "php artisan migrate --seed --database=codeception",
        "php artisan migrate --bench='hsd/catalog' --database=codeception",
        "php artisan migrate --bench='hsd/conversion' --database=codeception",
        "php artisan migrate --bench='hsd/emailsubscription' --database=codeception",
        "php artisan migrate --bench='hsd/html' --database=codeception",
        "php artisan migrate --bench='hsd/maxmind' --database=codeception",
        "php artisan migrate --bench='hsd/meta' --database=codeception",
        "php artisan migrate --bench='hsd/mobile' --database=codeception",
        "php artisan migrate --bench='hsd/postal' --database=codeception",
        "php artisan migrate --bench='hsd/smartlander' --database=codeception",
        "php artisan migrate --bench='hsd/sta' --database=codeception",
        "php artisan migrate --bench='hsd/upsell' --database=codeception",
        "php artisan db:seed --class='Hsd\\Catalog\\CatalogSeeder' --database='codeception'"
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you just need to remove the single quotes around the bench value.
I thought someone may be able to make use of this though.